# Applying as.numeric only to elements of a list that can be coerced to numeric (in R)

Tags: r

I have a function which returns a list containing individual character vectors which I would like to convert to numeric. Most of the time, all the elements of the list can easily be coerced to numeric:

and so a simple`lapply(x, FUN = as.numeric)` works fine.

e.g.

```
l <- list(a = c("1","1"), b = c("2","2"))
l
$a
[1] "1" "1"

$b
[1] "2" "2"


lapply(l, FUN = as.numeric)
$a
[1] 1 1

$b
[1] 2 2
```

However, in some situations, vectors contain true characters:

e.g.

```
l <- list(a = c("1","1"), b = c("a","b"))
l
$a
[1] "1" "1"

$b
[1] "a" "b"


lapply(l, FUN = as.numeric)
$a
[1] 1 1

$b
[1] NA NA
```

The solution I have come with works but feels a little convoluted:

```
l.id <- unlist(lapply(l, FUN = function(x){all(!is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))))}))

l.id
 a     b 
 TRUE  FALSE 

l[l.id] <- lapply(l[l.id], FUN = as.numeric)

l
$a
[1] 1 1

$b
[1] "a" "b"
```

So I was just wondering if anyone out there had a more streamlined and elegant solution to suggest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option would be to check whether all the elements in the vector have only numbers and if so convert to `numeric` or else stay as the same.

```
lapply(l, function(x) if(all(grepl('^[0-9.]+$', x))) as.numeric(x) else x)
```

Or we can use `type.convert` to automatically convert the `class`, but the `character` vectors will be converted to `factor` class.

```
lapply(l, type.convert)
```

Comment: i come up with `lapply(l, function(x){ifelse(grepl("^\\d+$",x), as.numeric(x), x)})`, what all means?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I think it can be also used, but if there are mixed class, it will come up with warnings. i.e. `l$a[2] <- 'a'`

Comment: @akrun In my case, the first option is most appropriate but good to know the second option for future reference.

Comment: @AnnaKrystalli Thanks for the feedback.  The `type.convert` is a convenient function.

Comment: @akun FYI the first option didn't work when there were punctuation marks in the strings (e.g. "2.0") so I combine yours with my original solution which now works:   `lapply(l, function(x) if(all(!is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))))) as.numeric(x) else x)`

Comment: @AnnaKrystalli I think you can use `grepl('^[0-9.]+$', x)`

Comment: "but the `character` vectors will be converted to `factor` class" -- Can't you use `type.convert()`'s `as.is = TRUE` option to prevent character vectors from being converted to factors?

Comment: @coip  Sure, you can do that.

Answer (score 3):

You could also do something like

```
lapply(l, function(x) if(is.numeric(t <- type.convert(x))) t else x)
# $a
# [1] 1 1
#
# $b
# [1] "a" "b"
```

This doesn't convert anything other than when a numeric results from `type.convert()`.  Or, for this simple case we can use `as.is = TRUE` but note that this will not always give us what we want.

```
lapply(l, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
# $a
# [1] 1 1
#
# $b
# [1] "a" "b"
```